# XMonad classic alt tab

Tags: xmonad

Is it possible for XMonad to behave like many window managers with regard to switching active window using Alt-Tab keys? After some looking I've tried:

```
((mod1Mask, xK_Tab), cycleRecentWindows [xK_Alt_L] xK_Tab xK_Tab)
```

from *XMonad.Actions.CycleWindows* module. This configuration "almost" works. One issue is that I must execute the sequence slowly (just under 1 second I think). Other WMs I have do not suffer from this kind of input lag. The other issue is that it shuffles windows around, I would love to have alt-tab just switch focus to previous window.

Comment: i don't have my config here, but what i do is simply cycle the focus between windows from the current screen. If that's what you are looking for, i'll post the relevant line tomorrow

Comment: The default binding for meta-j, `((modm, xK_j), windows W.focusDown)`, sounds like what you want, but I figure you already dismissed that option for some reason. Could you describe more precisely what you want, that the `focusDown` action doesn't do?

Comment: Come to think of it, what I meant by "previous" is how "classic" implementation lets you pick from implicit stack of windows. Switching works by pulling selected window to the top. In case of single press, you switch between window on top of the stack and one below it. You will not bring 3rd window to front without pressing switch combination twice in a row (keeping Alt key pressed). Actually, I find it very counter-intuitive when selection works just by cycling through all windows.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [GroupNavigation](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-GroupNavigation.html) for similar thing

Following example does cycle through windows on all workspaces:

```
import XMonad.Actions.GroupNavigation

...

((modm , xK_Tab), nextMatch Backward (return True))

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standalone application: https://github.com/sagb/alttab .
It pulls selected window to the top instead of shuffle and has special xmonad readme.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
…
-- Move focus to the next window.
, ((mod1Mask,                     xK_Tab), windows W.focusDown)
-- Move focus to the previous window.
, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask,       xK_Tab), windows W.focusUp  )
…
```

To cycle throw windows in the same desktop as indicated by [Neil Forrester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687277/xmonad-classic-alt-tab#comment25809613_17687277)